# How to pass Vue.js variable to Laravel Blade route helper

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

For example, I have a link to an other post like this in my template

```
<a href="{{ route('post', ['post' => @{{ post.id }}]) }}">My post</a>
```

I want to be able to use the post object within the route helper to use the id.

Is there any syntax for this use case?

Or is there an other way of doing this?

Comment: There's no syntax for this because Vue 2 doesn't allow string interpolation in HTML attributes anyway, edit your question and add your full view, where is the `post` object coming from?

Comment: Here's a very ugly way that you should definitely avoid https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-fwgmy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I had similar problems to solve this kind of cases. Your question related with Vue exactly, but the method below you can use for your case as well. Anyway you can't execute JS and PHP at the same time, cuz they're working at different sides. But as I also liked to have all routes with their aliases, I thought this approach.. You can imitate something like this:

```
Route::get('/', 'PostController@all')->name('all'); // all posts page
Route::get('post', 'PostController@all')->name('all_page'); // THIS IS THE THING (one additional route), WHICH WILL TAKE RESPONSIBILITY ON CASE, WHEN post_id WILL BE EMPTY
Route::get('post/{post_id}', 'PostController@post')->name('post');
```

This method will allow you to use the 1st and 3rd routes as normally, and as mixed too in the different places on your app like this:

```
{{ route('post.all') }}
{{ route('post', ['post' => $post_id]) }}
{{ route('post') }}/@{{ post.id }}
```

In scripts you can implement the approach like this:

```
let someUrl = "{{ route('post') }}/" + postObj.id;
```

In the view you can implement the method like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('post') }}/@{{ post.id }}">My post @{{ post.id }}</a>
```

Comment: Assuming the route param is always at the end but fine! it's a way

Comment: If you wanna make sure that the 'post_id' at the end is number/numeric, you can also write like this (regex validation rule in routers level)     Route::get('post/{post_id}', 'PostController@post')->name('post')->where('post_id','^([0-9]+)$');   But in latest versions of laravel anyway the system will thrown to the 404 Not found page

Comment: Thanks, for my case this will do it since it is at the end, but I wish there was a smarter way to do this now that we are using more and more Vue.js on our front mixed with some blade templates, smart!